# list-shard show more shards than provisioned

Tags: amazon-kinesis

I have a kinesis data stream which contains 4 shards. However when I use the following command:

```
aws kinesis list-shards \                                                      
    --stream-name stream --region us-east-1
```

I get more shards in response:

```
{
    "Shards": [
        {
            "ShardId": "shardId-000000000000",
            "HashKeyRange": {
                "StartingHashKey": "0",
                "EndingHashKey": "340282366920938463463374607431768211455"
            },
            "SequenceNumberRange": {
                "StartingSequenceNumber": "49629197963553601158578444092147254587573454320158375938",
                "EndingSequenceNumber": "49629197963564751531177709403716813520960387136782073858"
            }
        },
        {
            "ShardId": "shardId-000000000001",
            "ParentShardId": "shardId-000000000000",
            "HashKeyRange": {
                "StartingHashKey": "0",
                "EndingHashKey": "170141183460469231731687303715884105727"
            },
            "SequenceNumberRange": {
                "StartingSequenceNumber": "49629562583971205188053748556663691537888312852092026898",
                "EndingSequenceNumber": "49629562583982355560653013868233250471205027557631066130"
            }
        },
        {
            "ShardId": "shardId-000000000002",
            "ParentShardId": "shardId-000000000000",
            "HashKeyRange": {
                "StartingHashKey": "170141183460469231731687303715884105728",
                "EndingHashKey": "340282366920938463463374607431768211455"
            },
            "SequenceNumberRange": {
                "StartingSequenceNumber": "49629562583993505933252279179805227256160961213598007330",
                "EndingSequenceNumber": "49629562584004656305851544491374786189477675919137046562"
            }
        },
        {
            "ShardId": "shardId-000000000003",
            "ParentShardId": "shardId-000000000001",
            "HashKeyRange": {
                "StartingHashKey": "0",
                "EndingHashKey": "85070591730234615865843651857942052863"
            },
            "SequenceNumberRange": {
                "StartingSequenceNumber": "49629562611133512839864047543054196393974022389056405554"
            }
        },
        {
            "ShardId": "shardId-000000000004",
            "ParentShardId": "shardId-000000000001",
            "HashKeyRange": {
                "StartingHashKey": "85070591730234615865843651857942052864",
                "EndingHashKey": "170141183460469231731687303715884105727"
            },
            "SequenceNumberRange": {
                "StartingSequenceNumber": "49629562611155813585062578166195732112246670750562385986"
            }
        },
        {
            "ShardId": "shardId-000000000005",
            "ParentShardId": "shardId-000000000002",
            "HashKeyRange": {
                "StartingHashKey": "170141183460469231731687303715884105728",
                "EndingHashKey": "255211775190703847597530955573826158591"
            },
            "SequenceNumberRange": {
                "StartingSequenceNumber": "49629562611178114330261108789337267830519319112068366418"
            }
        },
        {
            "ShardId": "shardId-000000000006",
            "ParentShardId": "shardId-000000000002",
            "HashKeyRange": {
                "StartingHashKey": "255211775190703847597530955573826158592",
                "EndingHashKey": "340282366920938463463374607431768211455"
            },
            "SequenceNumberRange": {
                "StartingSequenceNumber": "49629562611200415075459639412478803548791967473574346850"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Why I am seeing more shards than provisioned ? I am looking to check hash ranges for the shards in order to determine wether they are evenly distributed or not but I am confused why I see more shards or where does they come from. Any ideas would be helpful.

Comment: Did you try applying filter using the `--shard-filter` option with type `AT_LATEST`?

Comment: More specifically, the `aws` CLI command option is `--shard-filter Type=AT_LATEST`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok I figured it out. It shows all the shards including the parent shards that have been split. If you want to get only active shards check for `EndingSequenceNumber` in response. The shards with `EndingSequenceNumber` are close shards. so in this I have only 4 shards which does not `EndingSequenceNumber` are hence are ACTIVE shards.

Answer (score 0):

Another way to display only open shards is to use `--shard-filter Type=AT_LATEST` parameter as Steve mentioned in the comment.